# To block some items in dropdown List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on MVC project and have a dropdown to fill with Country Name. But I want to block some country names so that they will not reflect in that dropdown. For blocked countries value of key should be listed in 'web.config' file. I do not want hard code. My current code is mentioned below. It will looks a little mixed up.

Step 1

```
private static void FillCombos(GuestInformationPresenter model)
{
    FillCountryLists(model);        
}
```

Step 2 // This code is written in GuestInformation  Controller

```
/// <summary>
/// Function to fill countries in combos.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">GuestInformationPresenter type of object</param>
private static void FillCountryLists(GuestInformationPresenter model)
{
    //I want to add some Linq code here to Block some countries. 
    model.FillCountryLists(ReservationService.RetrieveCountries());
}
```

Step 3 // This code is written in GuestInformation Presenter

```
public void FillCountryLists(Dictionary<string, string> countryList)
{
    this.CountryList = countryList;
}
```

Step 4 // Function to retrieve collection of Countries.
    /// 
    /// collection of countries
    public static KeyValuePair[] RetrieveCountries()
    {
        return LookupManager.RetrieveCountries();
    }

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> RetrieveCountries()
{
    KeyValuePair<string, string>[] countries = 
        CruiseLookup.RetrieveCountries();
    return countries.ToDictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>, string, string>(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
}
```

Step 5 // This code is written in LookManager.cs

```
public static KeyValuePair<string, string>[] RetrieveCountries()
{
    var countries = from LookupData.CountryRow countryRow in LookupManagerCache.Retrieve().CountryRows
    orderby countryRow.Name
    select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
        DataField.RetrieveValue(() => countryRow.Code),
        DataField.RetrieveValue(() => countryRow.Name));

    return countries.ToArray();
}
```

The method that does `return countries.ToArray();` (Step 5) is common to retrieve country list but when I want this list to bind GuestInformation Controller then I want to block those countries.

Currently from step 4 I am getting key-value pair of different countries. For example if country is Guiena then Key-value pair from step 4 will be
key='GU' value='GUIENA'

After that in step 3  I am using this code to remove 'Guiena' country

```
public void FillCountryLists(Dictionary<string, string> countryList)
{   
    countryList.remove(key="GU");
    countryList.remove(key="XYZ");  // Here XYZ is key of any other country
    this.CountryList = countryList;
}
```

**But I want to add some LINQ or other code in step 2 (at controller level) to remove countries.**

**The main thing that I want is that for blocked countries value of key should be listed in 'web.config' file**. Can you please assist me to fix it?

Comment: what is the issue? you cannot remove them in Step 2 ?

Comment: you can add them in web.config and read in controller

Comment: @EhsanSajjad  is it not possible using some Linq. The main thing that I want is that for blocked countries value of key should be listed in 'web.config' file. I am new to MVC,  can you please add some code help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes it is possible, you need to search on how to use custom keys in web.config and how to read them

Comment: You're giving us waaaaay too much information for such a simple problem. You simply need to ask how to filter out data from one collection using another collection - which you could have searched and found the answer quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Contains like this:

```
var excludeKeys = new string[] { "GU", "XYZ" };
var countries = from ....
                where !excludeKeys.Contains(your key field)
                orderby ....
                select ....;
```

So in order your codes, you need to pass excludeKeys to your RetrieveCounties method and use them in query.

Step 2

```
private static void FillCountryLists(GuestInformationPresenter model)
{
    var excludeKeys = new string[] { "GU", "XYZ" }; 
    model.FillCountryLists(ReservationService.RetrieveCountries(excludeKeys));
}
```

Step 5

```
public static KeyValuePair<string, string>[] RetrieveCountries(List<string> excludeKeys)
{
    var countries = from ....
                    where !excludeKeys.Contains(your key field)
                    orderby ....
                    select ....;
    return ....
}
```

It's enough to add an empty list to `RetrieveCountries` method to don't filter countries.

As mentioned in comments and in Ehsan Sajjad's answer, you can store these values as a comma separated string in web.config or a setting.setting file then retrieve it, split it, put in list and then pass to your method.

Comment: As I understand you are asking to add your code at step 5. But  I do not want to exclude countries at this level.
I want to exclude countries at controller level
What will be the code that we have to add in 'web.config' file?

Comment: Dear, may I know what do you mean by 'your key field'?  I am unable to get it.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I will add key values as a comma separated string in web.config as suggested by Ehsan Sajjad. But how I can retrieve them for your code. Can you please add code step by step for me, as  I am fresher in world of MVC so expecting help in detail.

Comment: @Web34 It seems the post answered your question  and it would be great if you accept/vote the answer. It's not compulsory at all but it makes the answer more useful for future readers and it's your kindness :)

Answer (score 0):

In your web.config add the list of blocked countries, or if you don't have that section add it under configuration section:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="BlockedCountries" value="GU,XYZ"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

and then in your controller:

```
 using System.Web.Configuration;
 ..............
 ..............




var blockedCountries =  WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlockedCountries"].Split(',',StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var result =  model.countries.Where(x=> !blockedCountries.Contains(x.Key)).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Ehsan.I apologize if I am asking stupid things.One doubt,  If I use your solution then is there any need to add code that suggested by Reza Aghaei and what is use of 'var result' in controller?

Comment: You can use that code as well, I just showed you how you can filter records on tha base of value from web.config @web34

Comment: but there is no way to add var result =  model.countries.Where(x=> !blockedCountries.Contains(x.Key)).ToArray(); in Controller. It's not working, can you please recheck it.

Comment: there is no way? what you mean by that?

Comment: countries option is not reflecting there. How can I pass 'blockedCounties' value to presenter ( at step 3) so that I can exclude values at presenter level by adding code countryList.Remove(key: blockedcountriesKey);